# create composite types using other types as variables

Tags: typescript

Lets assume I have the following type (just an example to make my point):

```js
type Alignment =
  "top left" |
  "middle left" |
  "bottom left" |
  "top center" |
  "middle center" |
  "bottom center" |
  "top right" |
  "middle right" | 
  "bottom right";
```

Is it possible to do something like this instead?

```js
type Vertical = "top" | "middle" | "bottom";
type Horizontal = "left" | "center" | "right";
type Alignment = `${Vertical} ${Horizontal}`;
```

EDIT
So I see my question was obsolete and its not about typescript at all, sorry but thanks for the answers, really helpfull.

Anyway, I get this error in VSCode, any idea?

[Parsing error: Type expected.eslint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RSvV.png)

Comment: You can try your code examples here https://www.typescriptlang.org/play
I see that your code working perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible since Typescript version 4.1!

You can read about template literal types here - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html

Here's your code in the Typescript playground where you can hover on the `Alignment` type to see what it looks like:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAahBOwCWBjAhgGygXigImAHsw8oAffAWyQBMaMJSK8AjQ4IyvAbgChRIUABKF4SAF6EAdsEw58DAGbAm+FBBkJVeMQHMAFir4DoAQQxJdUyhuDyABgBIA3nESpMAXyguRYyTJe9txAA